# Ruby - check for empty brackets

Tags: ruby

How to check if brackets or parenthesis are empty in a string in Ruby?

For example:

```
"Some text some text () some text some text" #=> Invalid string
```

A string with empty "()" or "[]" or "{}" should be false, otherwise true.

Examples:

```
"Some text some text (some text) some text some text" #=> Valid string
"Some text some text [some text] some text some text" #=> Valid string
"Some text some text {some text} some text some text" #=> Valid string

"Some text some text () some text some text" #=> Invalid string
"Some text some text [] some text some text" #=> Invalid string
"Some text some text {} some text some text" #=> Invalid string
```

I've been researching to use regular expressions or `scan` method, but none seems to fit my needs. How could I approach that?

Comment: Do you want the quick answer, or the correct one, that involves using Unicode definitions for symbol pairs and would be legit for anything that is declared as paired symbol in the Unicode Consortium definition?

Comment: You could simply check if the string contains `()`, `[]` or `{}`.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "a string with ... should be false, otherwise true". A string is not `true`, nor is it `false`.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, wasn't specific enough. Return false if brackets are empty, true otherwise.

Comment: @mudasobwa I would like the "correct" answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own method to do that.

Here's an example ([live](https://ideone.com/ZgPtzQ)):

```
def is_valid_string( s )
    brackets = %w[ () [] {} ]
    brackets.none? { |b| s.include?( b ) }
end

test_strings = [ 'hello (world)!', 'hello ()', 'test {}' ]

test_strings.each do |s|
    is_valid = is_valid_string( s )
    puts "#{s} -> #{ is_valid ? 'valid' : 'not valid' }"
end
```

Output:

```sh
hello (world)! -> valid
hello () -> not valid
test {} -> not valid
```

Comment: `brackets = %w[ () [] {} ]`. Also, consider using `brackets.none?` instead of abusing `each` with early return.

Comment: `def is_valid_string(s); %w[ () [] {} ].none?(&s.method(:include?)); end`

Comment: @mudasobwa: Thanks a lot! That was enlightening for me! :)

Comment: @mudasobwa you are a genius! I wish I were able to think programaticaly like you :D Can you help me understand this part `(&s.method(:include))`

Comment: @jedi `each` accepts either an explicit block or the `proc`. `s.method(:include)` returns a method `include` defined on `String` instance `s`, `&` converts it to `proc`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Hmm, why doesn't `%w[ () [] {} ]` parse as `%w[ () []` and then complain about `{} ]`? Is `%w` somehow eager, or does it ignore that first `]` because of the preceding `[`, or how? Couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, `%*` sigils are somehow eager, but I am unable to find the docs on it neither.

Comment: @mudasobwa Ok I don't think it's just eager. It does throw up at `%w[ () ] {} ]`. Though not at `%w[ () [ [ 3 ] ] {} ]` etc. Looks like it counts and matches `[` and `]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It depends on what we call “eager” :) Of course it counts the amount of opened/closed brackets, otherwise it would gorge everything till the last closing one.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, depends. What I meant with "eager" was something like "use the last `]` on the line of code". I think that might be reasonable as well. But really what I had expected originally was that it would take the *first* `]` and that we'd have to somehow escape it or use different delimiters, like `%w< ... >`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah, I hadn't thought of multiliners. It's not sigils, though, is it? Sigils as far as I know are symbols attached to *variables* to show type or scope. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)

Comment: @StefanPochmann I always lack the short term for those in ruby and I use the name that is set for them in [tag:elixir].

Comment: @mudasobwa I've seen them called "percent literals", for example [in this style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#percent-literals). Not exactly nice, I admit. But in our context, "multiline literals" would've been fine. Oh and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_%_Notation) I just saw *"delimiters can appear unescaped in the string as long as they are in balanced pairs"*.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer that comes to my mind would be to check if the string contains opening punctuation symbol immediately following by the closing one:

```
input =~ /\p{Ps}\p{Pe}/
```

Here is [the reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

Unfortunately, that’ll catch `"[)"` and other non-paired punctuation symbols. There is no way to test whether the closing one is the exact pair for the opening one within a single regexp (AFAIK,) so the next step would be probably required, that’ll check if the closing one is a pair to opening one.

To do so, one would need to parse [Names List](http://www.unicode.org/Public/10.0.0/ucd/NamesList.txt) (and maybe others) to find opening/closing pairs and validate they explicitly.

---

Bonus track: the solution above might also be a bit tweaked to catch proper Unicode quotes “” and many other symbols that are marked as paired punctuation (credits @StefanPochmann.) That way modern editors like Atom and VSCode highlight them:

```
input =~ /[\p{Ps}\p{Pi}][\p{Pe}\p{Pf}]/
```

or (check comments for details):

```
input =~ /\p{Ps}\p{Pe}|\p{Pi}\p{Pf}/
```

Comment: Or `input =~ Regexp.union('()', '[]', '{}')` for the ones specified in the question.

Comment: @Stefan nah :) the answer above actually has a value _for future readers_; that is why I ever bothered to write the answer instead of a comment.

Comment: For small number of pairs (3 in the OP), regexes are 3x slower. However, the `include?` solution scales much quicker with more pairs.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev plain wrong. It does not scale at all, mostly because _you have no idea what pairs are, while The Consortium has_. Also, my solution will work tomorrow, for Unicode 42.0.

Comment: @mudasobwa: this might be overengineering, some domains do have known (and closed!) set of pairs :) And it seems you misunderstood my comment about scaling.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ah, indeed, you meant regexp will outperform `include?` sooner or later :) Anyway, my experience always whispers to me: everything will change, stay prepared!

Comment: "Correct" is defined by the requirements. Matching too much can be as bad as matching too little.

Comment: @Stefan true that; on the other hand, for this particular case I saw many solutions matching too little and nearly none matching too much.

Comment: I don't think it's "unfortunate" that it catches `[)`, that looks even *more* invalid than `()`. A case where it actually looks wrong is `'the “]” char'`, as that string looks valid. But are you sure those quote characters get matched? I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @StefanPochmann indeed, you’re right, there are different classes for quotes: _`/\p{Pi}/` — 'Punctuation: Initial Quote'; `/\p{Pf}/` — 'Punctuation: Final Quote'_. But it’ll match `"(])"` which is probably not so good either.

Comment: About your edit: `/\p{Ps}\p{Pe}|\p{Pi}\p{Pf}/` might be also be good, that doesn't match my `“]”` example. But not sure what's better, other "mixed" cases might be desirable to catch.